# How can I accept a derived `shared_ptr` to a constructor accepting `T const &`?

Tags: c++

I have a class I use to combine a value and an error code. In a reduced form it looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper {
    T result;
    err_enum err;

    wrapper( T const & result ) :
        result( result ) {
        err = err_okay;
    }
}
```

I have a function that uses this as its return value:

```
wrapper<shared_ptr<base const>> foo() { ... }
```

The problem I'm having is that a class derived from `base` won't match this implicit constructor. I can't do, for example:

```
return make_shared<derived>();
```

I'm forced to do:

```
return wrapper<shared_ptr<base const>>(make_shared<derived>());
```

How can I write my `wrapper` class so that this implicit conversion is allowed?

*Note, the `wrapper` class must also accept types other than `shared_ptr`, such as plain struct/class types.*

Answer (score 0):

Add a templated constructor (optionally with perfect forwarding):

```
template <typename X>
wrapper( X && result) :
    result ( std::forward<X>(result)) /* error_code */ {}
```

This allows your wrapper to be constructed from anything that's convertible to the type of it's member. Note though that you're probably need some additional SFINAE logic in order to exclude copy/move constructors from this templated constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For `return make_shared<derived>();`, you're returning a `std::shared_ptr<derived>`, but the return type is `wrapper<shared_ptr<base const>>`. Then it has to be implicitly converted to `std::shared_ptr<base const>` then converted to `wrapper<shared_ptr<base const>>`. But only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one conversion sequence.

To solve it you can return a `wrapper<shared_ptr<base const>>` explicitly as you showed, or juse return a `shared_ptr<base const>` like:

```
return shared_ptr<base const>{make_shared<derived>()};
```